# Invalid column name after mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have added a (bit\bool) column `IsController` to one of my tables

```
ALTER TABLE P_USER ADD IsController bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Updated the edmx and added `IsController` to the `MY_USER` entity, then changed its name to 
`IsControllerX` and mapped it to the `IsController` from the table.

And set this inside the solution.domain.business cs file:

```
   public virtual bool IsControllerX { get; set; }
```

On debug I have the error:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details. InnerException: Invalid column name
>   'IsController'.

The error is with the `IsController` and not with `IsControllerX`! That is the name of the column that I mapped to - the name of the column inside the database!

Can someone please explain why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HOW** did you update your model and your generated classes??

In the EDMX, you should select the `Update Model From Database` option from the context menu, and then in the Update Wizard, you should pick your table that has been modified:

[image]

Doing this will properly update your EDMX and it works just fine in my scenario. Did you do it this way, and it still fails?? Or did you just do it manually ??

Comment: yes i did that exactly- exactly step by step - and i have this error - i must say that when i made the update it gave me an alert: Message 1 The table/view 'od.dbo.V_OD_LINK' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.  - i'm dont think that this is the reason ?can it be?

Comment: Does that view have any relationship with that table you're using here??

Comment: i must tell you that i'm new in entity framework and i dont use the views i use only the tables in the db - the column that i added was in the table and not in the view

Comment: i just found the prob!!! can you please tell me how can i choose the right databae on your screen above? cause i have 4 databases and it updates not from the right one

Comment: Each model has a connection string - usually in the web.config. That determines where your model points to.