# Invalid Column name when using savechanges() in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

So here is the deal, I have changed my database schema, and changed the PK for one of my tables and I have removed everything related to the old PK (FK reference in another tables).

However I have this exception when I insert a new entity using savechanges() method

> ex = {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

And the inner exception is

> InnerException = {"Invalid column name 'Audit_ID'."}

the Audit_ID is the old PK.

I have tried this
["Invalid column name" when trying to insert data into database using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051646/invalid-column-name-when-trying-to-insert-data-into-database-using-sql?rq=1)

this [Invalid column name when trying to add an entity to a database using DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490484/invalid-column-name-when-trying-to-add-an-entity-to-a-database-using-dbcontext)

this [Invalid column name after mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683482/invalid-column-name-after-mapping)

and nothing solved my issue, so as I deleted my whole edmx and created a new one also it didn't work.

ps: I am using database first approach

Comment: can you show the `savechanges()` `ef query` also ?

Comment: Usually removing old PK & adding new PK requires model update on DB first approach. If you had deleted all FK references for old `Audit_ID` PK, inside model class you can set `KeyAttribute` to assign new PK for database set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non of the solutions worked because the problem was actually in the SQL server database.

I ran SQL Profiler and executed the program insert statement, I found out that the error is in one of the table's triggers which has the Previous column name, changed that to the new PK and it finally worked.

So if anyone have a similar problem, the above links in the post might help or you should check if the problem was actually happening the Database server.

Comment: Holy crap, I owe you a beer.  I've been trying to find this problem for nearly 12 work hours.  Turns out the previous developer had written a trigger for the table.  You got me there, and I really appreciate it.  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Delete the table from the ef model(ensure that it is removed by looking at the model browser view).

Rebuild the solution.

Make sure your table has been saved. Check your connection strings as well that you are referencing the correct db.

Add the table again via the update model tool.

EDIT: read the question better

Comment: This is highly unlikely. Have you still got any foreign key connections on the ef?

Comment: _How_ has it made things worse?

Comment: When re-added the table, it wasn't added to the dbcontext. I manually added the table to the dbcontext but the whole solution was giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ModelKeyBuilder class.

```
class MyOwnModelKeyBuilder
{

    public static void BuildCompositeKeys(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
       .Ignore(x=>x.Audit_ID)
       .HasKey(x=>x.NewPrimaryKey);
    }
}
```

And in your Model.Context.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     MyOwnModelKeyBuilder.BuildCompositeKeys(modelBuilder); 
}
```

It may not be a straight solution because I don't know the tables structure but it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In may case, we found defining the database elemenents in the context fixed the issue.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("database_schema");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EntityNameInModel>().ToTable("table_in_database").HasKey(ats => ats.id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<EntityNameInModel>().Property(ats => ats.user_name).HasColumnName("user_name");
}
```

You will need to define every schema, table, and field in this way... but you'll have absolute control in your code after. Good luck!