# Adding & saving new records returns SqlException: Invalid column name 'BillingTypes_Id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have stucked from 2 days in this problem :(

I am trying to do "Home budget service" for me & wife. However, when I try to save changes to my DB I am still getting "SqlException: Invalid column name 'BillingTypes_Id'". I have seen many cases on stack with similiar titles, mainly:

[Invalid Column name when using savechanges() in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588868/invalid-column-name-when-using-savechanges-in-entity-framework)

My problem occurs during **_context.SaveChanges();**

Using VS 2017, EF 6.1.3

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class BillingViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<BillingTypes> BillingTypes { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "BillingTypes")]
        [Required]
        public int BillingTypesId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter cost.")]
        public double Cost { get; set; }

        public BillingViewModel(BillingTransaction billingTransaction)
        {
            Id = billingTransaction.Id;
            TransactionDate = billingTransaction.TransactionDate;
            BillingTypesId = billingTransaction.BillingTypesId;
            Cost = billingTransaction.Cost;
        }

        public BillingViewModel()
        {
            Id = 0;
            TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;
            Cost = 0;
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public class BillingTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BillingTypes BillingTypes { get; set; }

    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "BillingTypes")]
    [Required]
    public byte BillingTypesId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter cost.")]
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}

public class BillingTypes
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**BillingsController:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(BillingTransaction billingTransaction)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var types = _context.BillingTypes.ToList();

            var viewModel = new BillingViewModel
            {
                BillingTypes = types
            };

            return View("BillingForm", viewModel);
        }

        if (billingTransaction.Id == 0)
            _context.BillingTransactions.Add(billingTransaction);
        else
        {
            var transactionInDb = _context.BillingTransactions.Single(b => b.Id == 
            billingTransaction.Id);

            transactionInDb.Id = billingTransaction.Id;
            transactionInDb.TransactionDate = billingTransaction.TransactionDate;
            transactionInDb.BillingTypesId = billingTransaction.BillingTypesId;
            transactionInDb.Cost = billingTransaction.Cost;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Billings");

    }
```

Billings transactions table structure: (contains id, datetime, cost, billingtypeId)

[Screen][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyLZk.png

Billing types table structure: (contains id, name). For example: (1, "Alcohol")

[Screen][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4x3F.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Column name when using savechanges() in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588868/invalid-column-name-when-using-savechanges-in-entity-framework)

Comment: what is the reason using bytes ?
public byte BillingTypesId { get; set; }

Comment: Sayahimad - No, answer is below. Altaf - I am using bytes, because I do not need a big value for types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of your model's BillingTypesId property, add this decorator :

```
[ForeignKey("BillingTypes ")]
```

Your final code should look like this :

```
[Display(Name = "BillingTypes")]
[Required]
[ForeignKey("BillingTypes ")]
public byte BillingTypesId { get; set; }
```

This way EF will know BillingTypesId is the foreign key for BillingTypes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that Entity Framework can't infer the foreign key relationship between `BillingTransaction` and `BillingTypes`. You can either override `OnModelCreating` and use the fluent api, or you can use data annotations like so:

```
[Display(Name = "BillingTypes")]
[Required]
[ForeignKey("BillingTypes")]
public byte BillingTypesId { get; set; }
```

Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `public byte BillingTypesId { get; set; }` property from the `BillingTransaction` class. You are already defining the relationship by adding the `public BillingTypes BillingTypes { get; set; }` property.